# Documents as a node/block/field

Tags: 7, files

I'm working on my first Drupal site.

Using [FileViewer](http://drupal.org/project/fileviewer) I can load a PDF saved in a field, for viewing of various types. I haven't found something that does the same for Word Docs, Excel, etc.

Does anyone know of something that works in Drupal 7 to load documents other than PDF like FileViewer does inside a browser? Or like [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) does (Scribd is hosted. I am behind a firewall with limited access for users. So I don't want to use a Scribd like service.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that FileViewer has been folded into a module called [PDF](http://drupal.org/project/pdf), which uses JavaScript to render PDF files.

So the next logical question is: How do you render Word docs, like Google Docs? And the answer is: [Google Docs Integration module](http://drupal.org/project/google_docs), which lets you show a list of Google docs, but doesn't let you display the documents.

Web searches give up nothing else.

Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin [Embedded Google Docs Viewer](https://www.drupal.org/project/gdoc_field)

There are steps you should take:

1. Go to Structure -> Content Types -> YOUR_TYPE -> Manage Fields
2. Add a new field with type "File"
3. Go to Manage Display -> YOUR NEW FIELD -> Format and change it to Embedded Google Docs View

   Your content will be displayed in an IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

This question in Stack Overflow might help you: [reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php).

Note that that solution talks about a PHP interface to Microsoft office, not a Drupal module.